# Hard time understanding how to dispatch actions and pass props/state to child components

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

**Problem:** I have been scouring google, reading the redux.js.org documentation, looking at examples (but every example is diff from each other and from what I have) and can not figure out how to get my action creators to dispatch my actions or how I dispatch the actions of my action creators, or pass down my state etc. I am just trying to add a simple to do item to a list.

**Desired Result:** I Need a better ELI5 explanation of how I can dispatch actions of my action creators, how I can pass down the state of my mapStateToProps, because these examples are confusing me. I just want to add a simple item to my list and render the current state of my items.

I just want some guidance, I am not looking for anyone to do this for me, I have been enjoying learning so far, but this has been a brick wall for the last day or so. I hope the links suffice each one represents a diff part of my app. If you need to you can clone it here: http://github.com/laere/therealapp

**UPDATE:** Currently working on re-creating the problem in a single JSBIN: http://jsbin.com/yowenodaze/edit?js,console,output

**My Code:**

My Store (reducer/action creators): http://jsbin.com/zopedipezu/edit?html,js,output

My main root file where my store is. http://jsbin.com/tapowagobo/edit?html,js,output

My main container/parent component that makes the connect() to reference the store. http://jsbin.com/larisifube/edit?js,output

My List component(dumb component): http://jsbin.com/zirozucehi/edit?html,js,output

My ListItem component (dumb component): http://jsbin.com/sijifeqalu/edit?html,js,output

**UPDATE** I solved this issue. Upon making a connect to the store within my main container component, I was able to pass down action creators via this.props. to other components!

Comment: Your reducer is not a pure function (it's only mutating the state). You should watch dan_abramov's redux's course: https://egghead.io/series/getting-started-with-redux

Comment: I have watched his video course, but it was really hard to follow what he was doing. I guess It requires a re-watch.

Comment: Also is it because I have state.items = state.items.concant(stuff here)?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant by pure reducer. But I can't answer you about your specific problem, your code is splitted in multiple places (github / jsbin ..). Please provide a simplified example (or at least an example that can be ran in one place), this will increase your chances to get an answer (make it easy for people to understand **what's** your problem / **how** to reproduce it).

Comment: I am trying to recreate it, but having a hard time doing so. I don't really know where to begin with recreating it. I have tried putting it in jsbin but can't get anything working.

Comment: If you solved the issue please provide and accept your own answer so it isn’t tagged as unanswered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realized upon some more research and tinkering, I came to the conclusion that I am able to pass down my actions via props, like any other data would be passed down within the React Framework.

```
export default class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ChildComponent myState={this.props.myState}/>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = () => {
     return {
        myState: myState
  }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, as far as I can see the declaration of mapStateToProps there does nothing at all (but the first part of the code has the answer to a similar question I had!).  For mapStateToProps to do something, it has to be passed to `connect()`.  Maybe you do that, but didn't show it?